# Serialize protocol buffer objects to a string in ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to serialize objects generated from protocol buffer for objective C.

I used the method:

```
[protocObj data]
```

to serialize data but it returns an NSData object which contains many zero bytes so when I try to convert it to string to send, it's not converted with it's full size.
Example:

```
NSData: <09000000 00000040 40110000 00000080 40401900 00000000 00414021 00000000 00804140 28013500 00a04038 2b407b>

string:  "\t"
```

I understand that 00 is translated to \0 (string null termination) in UTF8.

So how to convert it properly ?

Comment: Why do you want to convert it to string? The HTTPBody property of NSURLRequest is NSData.

Comment: I want to send it to another app which is implemented with other languages and decode it using protocol buffer also.

Comment: How do you want to send it to the other app? Is the other app also released with the same developer account?